# can i pushreplace screen like native navigator in go router in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my app, i am using [`go_router`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) package available on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/) which is also a **flutter favourite package** but i am struggling to find a way to **pushreplace screen** with this package.

with default navigator push replacement is possible as below:

```
 void nextScreenReplace(context,Widget page) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => page));
    }
```

**i want this same functionality with go_router**

Comment: Can you please attach your code snippet at here with bug if  you have any in that ? So that I get clear idea about what you want to achieve in your code?

Comment: i could not find any function on pub.dev doc so i don't know, i know only push and go

Comment: Generally I am doing normal way for pushReplacement as you attach above. So I don't know about exact idea , but I open issue with this package , you will see in that. 
https://github.com/csells/go_router/issues/291

Answer (score 0):

use the `GoRouterHelper` extension on `BuildContext`

```
context.pushReplacement('Your page path registed to your app router');
```

or

```
context.pushReplacementNamed('Your page name registed to your app router');
```